# Cross-compiled library not found by toolchain

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm

I'm new to developing for embedded systems,  but I have installed arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc via the Linux Mint package manager and managed to build a few programs successfully.

I'm currently struggling with getting a program to compile using libusb. I've done the following:

- Downloaded and unpacked the libusb 1.0.20 sources from https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/.
- Compiled and installed them using the following commands:

~/Downloads/libusb-1.0.20 $ ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/opt/ --disable-udev

~/Downloads/libusb-1.0.20 $ sudo make

~/Downloads/libusb-1.0.20 $ sudo make install

(The reason for sudo-ing the make commands was because I encountered permission problems related to removing old files.)

- Copied a small sample file from somewhere on the internet:

  ```
  #include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main()
  {
    int i=0;
    libusb_context **c = NULL;
    i = libusb_init(c);
    printf("\nusing libusb.h\n");
    return 0;
  }
  ```
- Tried to build it and run it with gcc:

~/Desktop/libtest $ gcc libtest1.c -o libtest1 -lusb-1.0

~/Desktop/libtest $ ./libtest1

using libusb.h

- However, when I try to do the same with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc, it can't find the library:

~/Desktop/libtest $ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc libtest1.c -o libtest1 -lusb-1.0

/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb-1.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Where did I go wrong? Is there something else I need to do in order to use the library? Did I fail at compiling the library for the arm compiler? I didn't include the compiler output here since it's quite long, but there are no obvious errors. This might be a very stupid question, but I'm completely clueless.

Comment: You need to tell the linker where to find your usb-1.0 library as it is install in /opt not the usual system default location.

Try to add `-L{PATH to your usb library}` when you try to compile.

Comment: @SSC: This worked perfectly! For clarity (if another user stumbles upon this), I added "-L /opt/lib/" to my compile command, and now it builds and runs just fine!

Comment: usually you install the library to the sysroot of the toolchain, so when the toolchian look for all libraries at SYSROOT, it can find it.